# Getting TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable with certain files when extracting rows with specific words?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm using the following code to extract rows with specific words, the code run perfectly with some files, but gave me `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable` for other files.

```
import re
import string
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import glob
import csv
import os
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np

keywords = {"oracles","mining","ico"}
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\split6_out.csv", error_bad_lines=False)#, 
sep="," , encoding="utf-8")
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for i in range(len(df.index)):
   if any(x in (df[' Tags'][i])  for x in keywords):
       output.loc[len(output)] = [df[j][i] for j in df.columns]

 output.to_csv(r"C:\Users\plit6_KW.csv")
```

How would I fix this issue? How do you skip or ignore rows with `NAN` or those causing the problem?
Here is the traceback:

```
     TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
     last)
     <ipython-input-1-b705d440e654> in <module>()
        17 
        18 for i in range(len(df.index)):
        ---> 19    if any(x in (df[' Tags'][i])  for x in keywords):
        20        output.loc[len(output)] = [df[j][i] for j in df.columns]
        21 

        <ipython-input-1-b705d440e654> in <genexpr>(.0)
        17 
        18 for i in range(len(df.index)):
        ---> 19    if any(x in (df[' Tags'][i])  for x in keywords):
        20        output.loc[len(output)] = [df[j][i] for j in df.columns]
        21 

        TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Comment: Hi, Farid! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide us with the full traceback of your program when it displays an error. Add said traceback in the question.